# Восстановление объектов, упакованных в строку

Tags: ооп, java

Есть классы разных типов (`Circle, Rectangle,` ...), но наследующих общий абстрактный класс `Figure`. Данные этих классов упаковываются в строковое поле специального объекта, который выглядит примерно так:

```
public class FigureProxy {
    private String data;

    public FigureProxy(String data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void figureRestore(){
        //Восстановление 
    }
}
```

Строка, в которую упаковываются данные классов фигур имеет примерный вид: "Название_фигуры,параметр1,параметр2,...,параметрN".
При дальнейшем парсинге этой строки в методе figureRestore класса FigureProxy, в зависимости от названия фигуры, необходимо создавать и возвращать объекты соответствующих типов. Как это сделать я не знаю. Может кто-нибудь направит на верное решение?

Comment: Вам нужна сериализация/десериализация. Гугл выдал вот такое: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: Вот как раз я сериализую в файл эти объекты и решил создать прокси-класс, в объект которого упаковываю данные моих классов, и сериализую и десериализую уже его. Но вот как потом правильно из строки восстановить, я не знаю.
идею брал отсюда(пункт 4):
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-5things1/

Answer (score 3):

Зачем изобретать велосипед? Давно уже существует признанное (и что важно кроссплатформенное) решение по сериализации Java объектов в JSon строку. Применительно к Java очень удобно использовать Google Gson:

```
Figire figure;

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(figure);  //строка содержащая сериализованное значение объекта

figureRestored = gson.fromJson(json, Figure.class); //десериализация
```